# identity vs appositive coreference

Tags: nlp

what is the difference between identity coreference and appositive coreference?
In the following sentence for example:

`Mohammad traveled to Washington last week. He was on leave of absence. The 30-year old man stayed in an hotel overlooking the National Mall.`

As per what I understand, there is an identity coreference between `Mohammad` and `he`. Is there an appositive coreference between `he` and `the 30-year old man`? or `Mohammad` and `the 30-year old man'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An appositive is a noun or noun phrase that renames another noun right beside it. Appositive can be a long or short combination of words. let's have a little example :
This impressive detective, Sherlock Holmes always solves all kinds of problems.

So no appositive coreference between "he" and "the 30-year old man"  or "Mohammad" and "the 30-year old man'".